# 2-part dust collector, loss of CFM or not?

Tags: dust-collection, sawdust

So I'm about to order a Grizzly G1028Z2 1-1/2 HP Dust Collector rated at 1300 CFM. I'm unsure if I should get a super Dust Deputy to go with it. Will I lose a lot of my CFM's if I do this?

Also, a side question: does is matter if I buy a super Dust Deputy or a regular Dust Deputy? I already have a normal Dust Deputy, would it work the same if I just have adapters for it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. I've changed the title and the wording of your Question slightly so that it doesn't come across as overly subjective which is against the guidelines here (see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) from the Help section).

Comment: Well, thank you for fixing my grammar but that didn't really answer my question.

Comment: @wear_a_respirator626 comments are not for answers. Graphus was showing how to craft a good question so you might attract good answers. The idea is that we all chip in to build a collection of Q&A. When you have time, please take a look at the [tour].

Comment: I use a dust deputy on a shopvac for my lathes. I wouldn't attempt to use it between the dust collector and a planer or jointer. Putting a dust deputy ahead of the dust collector is going to reduce the vaccum. Using a cyclone is a good idea since it mean you don't have to mess aound with that bag, but by all means, please get one that's designed to work with dust collectors rather than a shopvacs. Get one designed for 4 inch ducts.

Answer (score 1):

As advertised, it seems that the Dust Deputy is designed to extract dust from the air stream before being sucked into the filters of a shop vac while the Grizzly Dust collector is designed to collect most of the dust in the collection bag. Using a dust separator to extract dust may only be desirable to catch larger pieces of wood that could get caught in the collector fan.

I have a 2HP grizzly dust collector using 4" pvc pipe (40'of pipe) with three gates and 10' of flexible 4" hose to make final connections to freestanding equipment. I intercept large bits of wood in a metal trash can with a inexpensive cyclone type top. The system is pretty closed although there is some leakage at the trash can interceptor. If I keep all other gates closed, I get plenty of air flow back to the collector, enough to lift small pieces of wood such as a short pencil (don't ask how I know) up 7' vertically and across the balance of the system.  Whether you should get a 1 1/2 HP or a slightly larger unit depends upon your budget and how large (length of pipe and number of ports) the distribution system is.  I believe that a 1 1/2 HP unit should be adequate, but if you have the cash then I know that 2HP can work.